# Pass byte[] as parameter to rdlc

Tags: c#, report

I have a image field in the rdlc file.

The image is obtained from the **sql database**, then pass that **datatable(dtIssueStationeryDetailsEntity)** to the **myreportview** class.

Then asign the datatable to the datasource property of the reportViewer.

```
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dtIssueStationeryDetailsEntity);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
```

My question is->the image is not binded to the field. How to bind it?

**OUTPUT** obtained is : **Empty Image Field**

My Rdlc file :

I created a dataset-->Have a field->Signature(datatype byte[])-->This dataset signature property is mapped to the Image field in rdlc file

```
=First(Fields!Signature.Value, "DataSet2")
```

**NOTE:**

1.MIME type is image/jpeg tryed image/png also.

2.(In the DataSet) I also tried to change the datatype of the Signature property to System.GUID, System.Object also.

Comment: Then convert it to an image instead of a string.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The datatype of the parameter in the rdlc is string. so if u see the code i have to again convert the image to string

Comment: How would you convert an image to a string?

Comment: @PatrickHofman  1)-->Get the byte[] from db 2)--> Passing the byte[] to MemoryStream 3)-->Assigning the value to the datatable.                           4)-->parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Signature", Convert.ToString(dtIssueStationeryDetailsEntity.Rows[0]["Signature"])));